# Running a python script shell works, but trying it inside emacs It returns AtributeError apparently because of Venv Variables not being set

Tags: python, shell, emacs, virtualenv

I've got a flask application and it mostly runs smoothly and returns what is needed. I've got it configured with a virtual environment. and when ran in shell it works perfectly, the problems comes when I run it inside emacs. It seems that some Venv variables are not being set at the moment of running the variables are set inside the "activate" script.

The question is, why are these variables not being set.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You probably should post the question to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe you can give us the steps you do, and check if the venv variables are in fact set or not with a `env | grep YOUR_VAR`. Specifically, how do you run it inside emacs: shell-mode, M-x compile, term ?